# How to generate a list of year-months integers?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

The following code is a prediction about time series, but to predict I need to change the date in the variable 'ds'.

If you notice, I have the date 202108, that is the year 2021 and the 8th month, so I need to create a code to change the year and the month for some periods after.

So I need to change to the next period 202109, and when the year ends in 202112, pass to the next year and month 202201, then 202202 and so on.

For the info, I'm working in pandas and 'ds' is an integer, I would like to have 25 periods after.

Note: I was tiping the following code, but only serves for continuing numbers.

```py
aux=mlf.predict(12)
aux['ds']=[202108 + x for x in range(1,13)]
```

Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it with Pandas [date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) and Python [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) and [zfill](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill):

```py
import pandas as pd

ds = [
    int(f"{item.year}{str(item.month).zfill(2)}")
    for item in pd.date_range("2021-08-01", periods=25, freq="m")
]
```

```
print(ds)
# Output
[
    202108,
    202109,
    202110,
    202111,
    202112,
    202201,
    202202,
    202203,
    202204,
    202205,
    202206,
    202207,
    202208,
    202209,
    202210,
    202211,
    202212,
    202301,
    202302,
    202303,
    202304,
    202305,
    202306,
    202307,
    202308,
]
```